# can memcpy() be used to change "const" member data?

Tags: c++, member, assignment-operator

For a `struct` with `const` members

```
struct point { const int x; const int y; };
```

that is used as member data

```
struct Foo
{
    point pt{ 0, 0 };
    void move_x(int value);
};
```

How can `Foo::move_x()` be written to update `Foo::pt`?  Is it OK to use `memcpy()`?

```
#include <memory.h>
void Foo::move_x(int value)
{
    const point pt_{ pt.x + value, pt.y };
    (void) memcpy(&pt, &pt_, sizeof(pt_)); // pt = pt_;
}
```

This can be safely done using a pointer

```
#include <memory>
struct Bar
{
    std::unique_ptr<point> pPt_{ new point{ 0, 0 } };
    const point& pt() const {
        return *pPt_;
    }

    void move_x(int value) {
        pPt_.reset(new point{ pt().x + value, pt().y });
    }
};
```

but the `point` is then always stored on the heap rather than in `Bar`.

Note that clients don't really care about `point` at all:

```
   Foo foo;
   foo.move_x(314); // (314, 0)

   Bar bar;
   bar.move_x(3141); // (3141, 0)
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. If you want mutable `point`s, why deliberately make them immutable?

Comment: That's what mutable means. The whole point of your `point` definition is that `x` and `y` never change once they've been initialized.

Comment: @Dan, what you are trying to do is undefined however you reach your result: either through `memcpy` or storing the object in a `char[]`. However you store or change those variables, as long as you refer to `point::x` or `point::y`, the compiler will assume they cannot be changed and optimize certain parts of your code. The same applies when you access to a `point` through a reference. However, as you show, a pointer will help.

Comment: If you want something similar to C#'s mutable references to immutable objects, then a pointer is the way to go.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is clearly undefined behavior. Now, "can" this be done? Sure, it can, but only in the sense that the compiler will not complain. But one aspect of C++ is just because the compiler doesn't complain it doesn't mean that the resulting code will work right.

It's only a matter of time before someone writes some code that reads `pt`, calls `move_x()`, and then reads `pt` again.

A modern, optimizing compiler will rightfully assume that because the code is reading `const` instances, their values cannot change, and then proceed and optimize away the second read from `pt`, using the data cached from the first read of `pt`, in the CPU registers.

And then, the hapless programmer will spend a week trying to figure out why the code is clearly not doing what the program says it should be doing.

Comment: No. Once something is `const`, by definition it cannot be changed. It is forever `const`.

Comment: @Dan Why do you insist on trying to mutate immutable data? If internal code needs to modify data that external code can't modify, what you need is encapsulation, not some language hacks

Comment: Placement new will not work for the same reason. Nothing can be done to change the fundamental property that `const` data should be `const`, and the compiler is free to optimize away repeated references to the same `const` data. Whether the `const`-ness is subverted by `memcpy()`, or by placement new, makes no difference. Once a compiler sees `const` data, it is free to eliminate repeated references to it.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a compiler error trying to use `memcpy` with a `const` member as follows:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

struct foo
{
    public:
        foo(int init_x);
        const int x;
        int bar();
};

foo::foo(int init_x): x(init_x) {}

int foo::bar()
{
    int *y = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *y = 6;
    memcpy(&x, y, sizeof(int));
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo f{5};
    printf("%d\n", f.bar());
}
```

The above results in

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
    memcpy(&x, y, sizeof(int));
```

While I used `const int` in this example, you will find the same result if you instead use a `const int` pointer member, i.e.

```
const int *x;
```

But, if you remove the `const` descriptor and use:

```
int x;
```

(or `int *x;`, for that matter) the error no longer happens, and the program prints `6`, as one might expect.

So this begs the question, if you know something is going to be declared as `const`:

- If you have the ability to change the declaration, couldn't you remove `const` yourself?
- If you can't change the declaration, is there a good reason you're looking to break the "promise" that `const` makes?

Comment: The question is whether you can safely modify the const members of a non const object. Your answer demonstrates that you cannot modify a const object.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR Updated to discuss `const` members of non-`const` objects, but the idea is still largely the same. Using `memcpy` in a "defined" way such as this, you are not able to change `const` members. "Can" = probably, "should" = probably not